# Launching a python3 script from php : string encoding system issue

Tags: php, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

From a php script, I want to launch a python3 script whose job is to read a file.

- The php code looks like this :

  ```
  $command = "python3 ./toto.py" ;
  $r = shell_exec($command);
  ```
- the python3 script, `toto.py` looks like this :

  ```
  myfile = open('/tmp/file_to_play.txt', 'r')
  print(myfile.readline())
  ```
- the text file to be read is an utf-8 encoded file (note it contains a "é") :

  ```
  déclin_abeilles.mkv
  ```

When I launch the python3 script directly from the shell, it works properly.
However, when it is executed through the php script, I get a coding system error when I read the text file :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toto.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(myfile.readline())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anybody explain me what I am missing?

Note : everything runs on a raspberry 3 server with a "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" and defaults packages

Note 2 : the php code contains   `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: Does it work if you open your file with `myfile = open('/tmp/file_to_play.txt', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you. But I still don't understand what is going on. Why is there a different behavior when I launch the script through php?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I suspect that the shell in which PHP executes your command doesn't have the same environment as your main shell, and Python looks by default at the locale to determine the encoding to use for text files.  That's why forcing the encoding to utf-8 helps.

Comment: Assuming that by adding the explicit utf-8 encoding that it now works, I would think that because you are using PHP's shell_exec function to invoke the Python program, the actual output is now returned in the PHP program's $r variable. So, unless you output that variable in your PHP program, you will have no output at all.

Comment: You found my problem. The `$LANG` variable was set to `C` in the php environment whereas in my shell it is set to `fr_FR.UTF-8`. A `print(os.environ)` in python allows to checks that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

From what i know, some special characters can mess up programs. Try replacing your 'é' with an 'e'. See if that helps

Comment: Replacing the input of my program is not an option. And using utf-8 in python is supposed to overcome this kind of problems.